# App Engine Error when try to make Google OAuth in high traffic site - CRITICAL

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I have a site with options of Login with Google and Facebook.
My site has near 200 users and many of them make their logins at 13:00 hrs (Chilean Time).
Today we have a very critical error, when making the loging, we received the Google OAUTH 2 token response and when trying to get the user profile using this url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?.... (my app secret, token, etc)
The Google system started to answer with an error (this error was visible only in the urlfetch response of the app engine python app):

**"We're sorry...
... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
See Google Help for more information."**

I have been using the system for more than a year without problems but today, without any change in the code, started receiving this error during 15 minutes and make our system totally freezed due to nobody can login...

How can I prevent this doesn't happen again in the future?  If the google OAuth cant' support more than 200 users loging in in 1 minute I think is useless!!!! I decided to make pur app in app egine for scalability, but this issue make me think again...

Thank you

Rene Marty

Answer (score 1):

this may be related to an App Engine authentication issue tracked here: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15006